# Depending on field value change nested serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am currently trying to implement the following serializer to the Profile serializer. But I would like to add a condition to it.
Profile serializer

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    role = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=(('Reader', u'Reader'), ('Author', u'Author'), ('Admin', u'Admin')))
    role_display = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('gender', 'birthday', 'icon', 'role', 'role_display')
        depth = 1
```

Author serializer

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = '__all__'
```

Reader serializer

```
class ReaderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Reader
        fields = '__all__'
```

Both author and reader table has a one-to-one relationship towards profile table. 
Depending on the role option I would like to show a specific nested serializer.

Example:

```
{
    "id": 19,
    "username": "maoji1",
    "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$180000$YhzDiqzJ4OyC$syzkwR5X3/H2p5NTB0JEK2zS5nvYu5ddHrTgy3cYU/E=",
    "email": "pbkdf2_sha256$180000$YhzDiqzJ4OyC$syzkwR5X3/H2p5NTB0JEK2zS5nvYu5ddHrTgy3cYU/E=",
    "profile": {
        "gender": "male",
        "birthday": "2020-03-10",
        "icon": null,
        "role": {
            is_vip:True,
            validate_date:...
      }
    }
}
```

Reader model

```
class Reader(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reader', verbose_name='user')
    is_user_vip = models.CharField(choices=(('normal', u'Normal'), ('vip', u'VIP')),
                                   default='normal',
                                   max_length=10,
                                   verbose_name=u'Vip status')
    vip_validate = models.DateField(verbose_name=u"Validate Until",
                                    auto_now_add=True, null=True,
                                    editable=False)
```

Author model

```
class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author')
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Book', null=True)
    contract_number = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Contact number', null=True, blank=True)
```

Profile model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    role_choice = (
        ('Reader', u'Reader'),
        ('Author', u'Author'),
        ('Editor', u'Editor'),
        ('Admin', u'Admin')
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile', verbose_name='user')
    gender = models.CharField(choices=(("male", u"Male"), ("female", u"Female")),
                              default="Female",
                              max_length=150, verbose_name='Gender')
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Birthday")
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/image/%Y/%m",
                             default=u"media/image/default.png",
                             max_length=1000,
                             verbose_name=u"User icon", null=True)
    role = models.CharField(choices=role_choice,
                            max_length=150,
                            default='Admin',
                            verbose_name='Role')
```

Comment: Could you show your models?

Comment: @kamilyrb Just updated the question with my model

Comment: You want to change  value of "role" key based on user role am i right?

Comment: Yes, role field is currently linking to a choice, I have two identities, reader and author. I want the serializer to show specific identity serializer depending on the role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SerializerMethodField and decide which serializer you must use inside it's method:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = serializers.MethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'email','profile')

    def get_profile(self,obj):
         return ProfileSerializer(obj.profile).data


class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = Author
         fields ='__all__' 


 class ReaderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = Reader
         fields ='__all__'  




class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    role = serializers.MethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('gender', 'birthday', 'icon', 'role')

    def get_role(self,obj):
        if hasattr(obj, 'author')
            serializer = AuthorSerializer(obj.author)
            return serializer.data
        elif hasattr(self,'reader'):
            serializer = ReaderSerializer(obj.reader)
            return serializer.data
        return {} # if your profile doesn't have any relation with author or reader



 class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = serializers.MethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'email','profile')

    def get_profile(self,obj):
         return ProfileSerializer(obj.profile).data
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @kamilyrb

Comment: Sorry to tag you, another question with your method in the API view it does not allow me to edit the field anymore, how do I make the field editable?